# League Size = 0, Even Though Id Is Correct

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am attempting to update information in an SQLite Database.  The information being read by my getter is correct, but whenever I go to update the information within the record, i.e. League Name, Basis Score, etc.. I am being to told that the size of the array is 0.

I can see in the debug that I am calling the correct record id and the information that is being pulled from the database is correct.  This is confirming to me that the record is indeed the correct one.

I can see in the debug that the information is correct and the variables are storing the changes made to the record.

[image: Before changes are made to the data]

[image: After changes are made to the data]

Can't see to figure out what it is I am doing incorrectly.  I have gone through  several different posts on this site, including this one.[What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

I cannot seem to find anything that will assist me with resolving this. Can someone assist me with this please, I have posted my code below.

My code to get the record upon entering the Activity

```
public void getLeagueProfile(int position) {


        SQLiteOpenHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor viewLeagueProfile = db.query(League.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{League.COLUMN_ID, League.COLUMN_NAME, League.COLUMN_BASE_SCORE, League.COLUMN_BASE_SCORE_PERCENTAGE, League.COLUMN_WINS, League.COLUMN_LOSSES, League.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP}, League.COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(position)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (viewLeagueProfile.moveToFirst()) {

            //Prepare League Object
            league = new League(viewLeagueProfile.getInt(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_ID)), ln = viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_NAME)), bs = viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_BASE_SCORE)), bsp = viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_BASE_SCORE_PERCENTAGE)), lw = viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_WINS)), ll = viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_LOSSES)), viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

            Log.e("values : ", ln + ", " + bs + ", " + bsp + ", " + lw + ", " + ll);

            final EditText leagueName = findViewById(R.id.etLeagueName);
            final EditText basisScore = findViewById(R.id.etBasisScoreValue);
            final EditText basisScorePercentage = findViewById(R.id.etBasisScorePercentageValue);
            final EditText leagueWins = findViewById(R.id.etLeaguePointsWon);
            final EditText leagueLosses = findViewById(R.id.etLeaguePointsLost);

            leagueName.setText(ln);
            basisScore.setText(bs);
            basisScorePercentage.setText(bsp);
            leagueWins.setText(lw);
            leagueLosses.setText(ll);

            Log.v("Cursor Object", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(viewLeagueProfile));

            //Close Database Connection
            viewLeagueProfile.close();
        }
    }
```

My code to update the record in the database when Save is clicked

```
private void updateLeague(String ln, String bs, String bsp, String lw, String ll, final int position) {

        League n = leaguesList.get(position);

        //Updating League Text
        n.setName(ln);
        n.setBaseScore(bs);
        n.setBaseScorePercentage(bsp);
        n.setWins(lw);
        n.setLosses(ll);

        //Updating The League In The Database
        db.updateLeague(n);

        //Refreshing The List
        leaguesList.set(position, n);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
```

My Update function in my DatabaseHelper.java

```
public int updateLeague(League league) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(League.COLUMN_NAME, league.getName());
        values.put(League.COLUMN_BASE_SCORE, league.getBaseScore());
        values.put(League.COLUMN_BASE_SCORE_PERCENTAGE, league.getBaseScorePercentage());
        values.put(League.COLUMN_WINS, league.getWins());
        values.put(League.COLUMN_LOSSES, league.getLosses());

        //Updating Row
        return db.update(League.TABLE_NAME, values, League.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(league.getId())});
    }
```

The debug console log

```
09/27 16:29:25: Launching app
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of D:\Documents\Android Studio Project\tpbcUI\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop ca.rvogl.tpbcui
$ adb shell am start -n "ca.rvogl.tpbcui/ca.rvogl.tpbcui.views.SplashActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: ca.rvogl.tpbcui | ca.rvogl.tpbcui.test
Waiting for application to come online: ca.rvogl.tpbcui | ca.rvogl.tpbcui.test
Connecting to ca.rvogl.tpbcui
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
    waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8635', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1341)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/ca.rvogl.tpbcui-2/lib/x86
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9cfff640, tid 6650
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9bcdf080, tid 6666
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa0485120: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0485120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa0483130)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0485120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa0483130)
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/ViewConfigCompat: Could not find method getScaledScrollFactor() on ViewConfiguration
D/id: 4
D/leagueId: 4
D/id: 3
D/leagueId: 3
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=12KB, data=19KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=12KB, data=19KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=12KB, data=38KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=12KB, data=38KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
I/art: JIT allocated 60KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
    Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
D/id: 2
D/leagueId: 2
D/id: 1
D/leagueId: 1
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0485120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa0483130)
I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=81KB, data=55KB
I/art: Starting a blocking GC JitCodeCache
I/art: After code cache collection, code=79KB, data=43KB
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0485120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa0483130)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0485120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa0483130)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0485120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa0483130)
D/leagueId: 0
E/values :: Saturday Practice Bowling, 190, 100, 0, 0
V/Cursor Object: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@ae7b8b5
    0 {
       _id=4
       name=Saturday Practice Bowling
       basescore=190
       basescorepercentage=100
       wins=0
       losses=0
       timestamp=2018-09-20 17:58:16
    }
    <<<<<
E/values :: Saturday Practice Bowling, 190, 100, 0, 0
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=118KB, data=89KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=115KB, data=87KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0485120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa0483130)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0485120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa0483130)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0485120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa0483130)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0485120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa0483130)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0485120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa0483130)
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x8b721c80 (MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView) with handle 0x8cdb7740
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0485120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa0483130)
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
E/values :: Saturday Practice Bowling, 190, 100, 0, 0
V/Cursor Object: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@66308ae
    0 {
       _id=4
       name=Saturday Practice Bowling
       basescore=190
       basescorepercentage=100
       wins=0
       losses=0
       timestamp=2018-09-20 17:58:16
    }
    <<<<<
I/art: JIT allocated 61KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=245KB, data=147KB
    Starting a blocking GC JitCodeCache
    After code cache collection, code=175KB, data=97KB
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0485120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa0483130)
```

If I missed posting something could help with resolving this please let me know and I will gladly post it.

```
2018-09-27 16:08:09.615 5820-5820/ca.rvogl.tpbcui E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ca.rvogl.tpbcui, PID: 5820
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
        at ca.rvogl.tpbcui.views.LeagueProfileEditActivity.updateLeague(LeagueProfileEditActivity.java:189)
        at ca.rvogl.tpbcui.views.LeagueProfileEditActivity.access$000(LeagueProfileEditActivity.java:28)
        at ca.rvogl.tpbcui.views.LeagueProfileEditActivity$1.onClick(LeagueProfileEditActivity.java:124)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
```

I am getting it on this line `League n = leaguesList.get(position);`

Activity Code:

```
public class LeagueProfileEditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    League league;
    public List<League> leaguesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private LeagueAdapter mAdapter;

    public DatabaseHelper db;

    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
    private static final String PREF_BLUE_THEME = "blue_theme";
    private static final String PREF_GREEN_THEME = "green_theme";
    private static final String PREF_ORANGE_THEME = "purple_theme";
    private static final String PREF_RED_THEME = "red_theme";
    private static final String PREF_YELLOW_THEME = "yellow_theme";

    public String ln, bs, bsp, lw, ll;
    public int leagueId;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        //mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged(db.getAllLeagues());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Use Chosen Theme
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean useBlueTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_BLUE_THEME, false);
        if (useBlueTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Blue_NoActionBar);
        }
        boolean useGreenTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_GREEN_THEME, false);
        if (useGreenTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Green_NoActionBar);
        }
        boolean useOrangeTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_ORANGE_THEME, false);
        if (useOrangeTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Orange_NoActionBar);
        }
        boolean useRedTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_RED_THEME, false);
        if (useRedTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Red_NoActionBar);
        }
        boolean useYellowTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_YELLOW_THEME, false);
        if (useYellowTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Yellow_NoActionBar);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_league_profile_edit);

        mAdapter = new LeagueAdapter(this, leaguesList);

        String savedLeagueId = String.valueOf(getIntent().getIntExtra("leagueId",2));
        leagueId = Integer.valueOf(savedLeagueId);

        getLeagueProfile(leagueId);

        final Button save_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave);
        save_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                final EditText leagueName = findViewById(R.id.etLeagueName);
                final EditText basisScore = findViewById(R.id.etBasisScoreValue);
                final EditText basisScorePercentage = findViewById(R.id.etBasisScorePercentageValue);
                final EditText leagueWins = findViewById(R.id.etLeaguePointsWon);
                final EditText leagueLosses = findViewById(R.id.etLeaguePointsLost);

                int leagueId = league.getId();

                updateLeague(league, leagueName.getText().toString(), basisScore.getText().toString(), basisScorePercentage.getText().toString(), leagueWins.getText().toString(), leagueLosses.getText().toString(), leagueId);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LeagueProfileViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("leagueId", leagueId);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

            }

        });

        final Button cancel_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCancel);
        cancel_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                int leagueId = league.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LeagueProfileViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("leagueId", leagueId);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }

        });

    }

    public void getLeagueProfile(int position) {


        SQLiteOpenHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor viewLeagueProfile = db.query(League.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{League.COLUMN_ID, League.COLUMN_NAME, League.COLUMN_BASE_SCORE, League.COLUMN_BASE_SCORE_PERCENTAGE, League.COLUMN_WINS, League.COLUMN_LOSSES, League.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP}, League.COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(position)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (viewLeagueProfile.moveToFirst()) {

            //Prepare League Object
            league = new League(viewLeagueProfile.getInt(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_ID)), ln = viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_NAME)), bs = viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_BASE_SCORE)), bsp = viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_BASE_SCORE_PERCENTAGE)), lw = viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_WINS)), ll = viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_LOSSES)), viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

            Log.e("values : ", ln + ", " + bs + ", " + bsp + ", " + lw + ", " + ll);

            final EditText leagueName = findViewById(R.id.etLeagueName);
            final EditText basisScore = findViewById(R.id.etBasisScoreValue);
            final EditText basisScorePercentage = findViewById(R.id.etBasisScorePercentageValue);
            final EditText leagueWins = findViewById(R.id.etLeaguePointsWon);
            final EditText leagueLosses = findViewById(R.id.etLeaguePointsLost);

            leagueName.setText(ln);
            basisScore.setText(bs);
            basisScorePercentage.setText(bsp);
            leagueWins.setText(lw);
            leagueLosses.setText(ll);

            Log.v("Cursor Object", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(viewLeagueProfile));

            //Close Database Connection
            viewLeagueProfile.close();
        }

    }

        private void updateLeague(final League league, String ln, String bs, String bsp, String lw, String ll, final int position) {

        League n = leaguesList.get(position);

        //Updating League Text
        n.setName(ln);
        n.setBaseScore(bs);
        n.setBaseScorePercentage(bsp);
        n.setWins(lw);
        n.setLosses(ll);

        //Updating The League In The Database
        db.updateLeague(n);

        //Refreshing The List
        leaguesList.set(position, n);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.league_profile_edit_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_cancel) {
            /*Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);*/
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include where you are getting the Array Out of Bounds and the stack-trace when you get it.

Comment: @MikeT  I posted the logcat and the particular line it is failing on above.

Comment: It seems you are never populating `leaguesList`. `getLeagueProfile` creates a new `League` Object but its not set/saved to `leaguesList` there, right?

Comment: leaguelist is empty as per `League n = leaguesList.get(position);
` you need to populate it.

Comment: So `leaguesList` is causing the exception.... But your code doesn't include where you declare / populate this variable..

Comment: @MikeT  Isn't the following code populating  leagueList `League league;
    private List<League> leaguesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private LeagueAdapter mAdapter;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is that `leaguesList` is an empty List, thus `League n = leaguesList.get(position);` is trying to get the 4th element out of 0 elements. Hence the exception.

> @MikeT Isn't the following code populating leagueList League league;
>   private List leaguesList = new ArrayList<>(); private
>   LeagueAdapter mAdapter;

NO. `League league;` (with class scope) has nothing to do with `private List leaguesList = new ArrayList<>();` other than they are of the same type. So using `getLeagueProfile(leagueId);` just sets(instantiates) the **league** variable/object.

I don't believe that you need leaguesList nor mAdapter. I believe you need the following (i.e. just use the single **league** variable):-

```
public class LeagueProfileEditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    League league;
    //public List<League> leaguesList = new ArrayList<>(); //<<<<<<<<<< DELETED
    //private LeagueAdapter mAdapter; //<<<<<<<<<< DELETED

    public DatabaseHelper db;

    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
    private static final String PREF_BLUE_THEME = "blue_theme";
    private static final String PREF_GREEN_THEME = "green_theme";
    private static final String PREF_ORANGE_THEME = "purple_theme";
    private static final String PREF_RED_THEME = "red_theme";
    private static final String PREF_YELLOW_THEME = "yellow_theme";

    public String ln, bs, bsp, lw, ll;
    public int leagueId;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        //mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged(db.getAllLeagues()); //<<<<<<<<<< Not needed
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Use Chosen Theme
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean useBlueTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_BLUE_THEME, false);
        if (useBlueTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Blue_NoActionBar);
        }
        boolean useGreenTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_GREEN_THEME, false);
        if (useGreenTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Green_NoActionBar);
        }
        boolean useOrangeTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_ORANGE_THEME, false);
        if (useOrangeTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Orange_NoActionBar);
        }
        boolean useRedTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_RED_THEME, false);
        if (useRedTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Red_NoActionBar);
        }
        boolean useYellowTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_YELLOW_THEME, false);
        if (useYellowTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Yellow_NoActionBar);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_league_profile_edit);

        //mAdapter = new LeagueAdapter(this, leaguesList); //<<<<<<<<<< not needed

        String savedLeagueId = String.valueOf(getIntent().getIntExtra("leagueId",2));
        leagueId = Integer.valueOf(savedLeagueId);

        getLeagueProfile(leagueId); //<<<<<<<<<< sets the values for league

        final Button save_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave);
        save_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                final EditText leagueName = findViewById(R.id.etLeagueName);
                final EditText basisScore = findViewById(R.id.etBasisScoreValue);
                final EditText basisScorePercentage = findViewById(R.id.etBasisScorePercentageValue);
                final EditText leagueWins = findViewById(R.id.etLeaguePointsWon);
                final EditText leagueLosses = findViewById(R.id.etLeaguePointsLost);

                int leagueId = league.getId();

                updateLeague(league, leagueName.getText().toString(), basisScore.getText().toString(), basisScorePercentage.getText().toString(), leagueWins.getText().toString(), leagueLosses.getText().toString(), leagueId);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LeagueProfileViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("leagueId", leagueId);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

            }

        });

        final Button cancel_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCancel);
        cancel_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                int leagueId = league.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LeagueProfileViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("leagueId", leagueId);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }

        });

    }

    public void getLeagueProfile(int position) {


        SQLiteOpenHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor viewLeagueProfile = db.query(League.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{League.COLUMN_ID, League.COLUMN_NAME, League.COLUMN_BASE_SCORE, League.COLUMN_BASE_SCORE_PERCENTAGE, League.COLUMN_WINS, League.COLUMN_LOSSES, League.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP}, League.COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(position)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (viewLeagueProfile.moveToFirst()) {

            //Prepare League Object
            league = new League(viewLeagueProfile.getInt(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_ID)), ln = viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_NAME)), bs = viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_BASE_SCORE)), bsp = viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_BASE_SCORE_PERCENTAGE)), lw = viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_WINS)), ll = viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_LOSSES)), viewLeagueProfile.getString(viewLeagueProfile.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

            Log.e("values : ", ln + ", " + bs + ", " + bsp + ", " + lw + ", " + ll);

            final EditText leagueName = findViewById(R.id.etLeagueName);
            final EditText basisScore = findViewById(R.id.etBasisScoreValue);
            final EditText basisScorePercentage = findViewById(R.id.etBasisScorePercentageValue);
            final EditText leagueWins = findViewById(R.id.etLeaguePointsWon);
            final EditText leagueLosses = findViewById(R.id.etLeaguePointsLost);

            leagueName.setText(ln);
            basisScore.setText(bs);
            basisScorePercentage.setText(bsp);
            leagueWins.setText(lw);
            leagueLosses.setText(ll);

            Log.v("Cursor Object", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(viewLeagueProfile));

            //Close Database Connection
            viewLeagueProfile.close();
        }
    }

        private void updateLeague(final League league, String ln, String bs, String bsp, String lw, String ll, final int position) {

        //League n = leaguesList.get(position); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ERROR

        //Updating League Object
        //n.setName(ln); //<<<<<<<<<< replaced by
        league.setName(ln)
        //n.setBaseScore(bs); //<<<<<<<<<< replaced by
        league.setBaseScore(bs);
        //n.setBaseScorePercentage(bsp); //<<<<<<<<<< replaced by
        league.setBaseScorePercentage(bsp);
        //n.setWins(lw); //<<<<<<<<<< replaced by
        league.setWinds(lw);
        //n.setLosses(ll); //<<<<<<<<<< replaced by
        league.setLosses(ll);

        //Updating The League In The Database
        db.updateLeague(league);

        //Refreshing The List
        //leaguesList.set(position, n); //<<<<<<<<<< DELETED NOT USED????
        //mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position); //<<<<<<<<<< DELETED NOT USED????
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.league_profile_edit_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_cancel) {
            /*Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);*/
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

- **Notes**
- The above is in-principle code, it has not been tested not syntax checked. So it may contain errors.
- The above code has been written with no knowledge of the Options Menu content, so the codes makes no consideration for any impact that may have.

Comment: MikeT you are correct, the changes you made worked.  How do you determine whether or not an Array<List> is needed or not?  I think this is where my problem is, I am unable to determine when one method is better suited versus another

Comment: If only dealing with one League, such as when editing or deleting a league then there is no need for a list. Generally you'd only need a list when presenting a list. So typically an App would display a list and allow a selection from that list so handling that selected item only then needs to deal with a single item.

Comment: Thanks I will keep this in mind.  What if I am creating a new league that never existed before would the same hold true editing or deleting a league?

Comment: Adding a new league would be similar to edit, except you don't need to pass anything to the add/insert activity.

Comment: Thanks again MikeT